# How to read lines from multiple files using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, io-redirection

I have three files, lets call them fileA fileB and fileC.

fileA:

```
This
sentence
to
```

fileB:

```
is
I
write
```

fileC:

```
the
want
.
```

Is there a way to loop through fileA then fileB then fileC etc. to show

```
This is the sentence I want to write .
```

in another text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need everything on one line, this will do:

```
$ paste fileA fileB fileC
This    is      the
sentence        I       want
to      write   .
```

If you want it all on one line,

```
$ echo $(paste fileA fileB fileC)
This is the sentence I want to write .
```